# Entering UTF-8 characters into Sublime Text 2 on Ubuntu

Tags: utf-8, sublimetext2

I have looked all over, but I cannot figure this out.

I want to enter some 2-byte characters into Sublime Text 2, and I can't figure out how to do it. The standard way on Linux is CTRL-SHIFT-u followed by 4 hex digits. This does not work in Sublime Text 2. How is it done??

And, please, if this *is* documented somewhere, please tell me *where*???

Comment: Have you tried copy pasting the character you're looking for?

Comment: yes, i know i could do that, but that is rather a silly hack. why can't i type them directly into ST2?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, I remember something about this in the Sublime Text forums... You might better results asking over at their forums: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/